# Elementary OS and Steam, Games not working

Tags: release-hera, steam

I have recently installed Steam and downloaded A Plague Tale:Innocence, and Red Dead Redemption 2.

A Plague Tale:Innocence in particular because A) It is rated Platinum on protondb.com and B) It worked fine on this machine when I had it as dual boot. In other words I know it should work fine.

At the moment what is happening is this:

I click the icon for A Plague Tale:Innocence

The Steam window comes up telling me it is about to launch the game.

The screen goes blank

We go back to where we were

I have installed proton 5.0.9 and checked all the user question boards I can but I can find no-one else with the same problem.

Any help gratefully received, I have the feeling I missing something simple.

I would rate myself a noob in the world in Linux.

Many thanks.

My technical details are below:

=============================

elementary OS 5.1.5 Hera

Built on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Linux 5.3.0-61-generic

GTK 3.22.30

=============================

Quad-Core Intel® Core™ i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz

Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)

19,6 GB memory

491,2 GB storage (NVMe SSD)